# Pop up window from hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
HyperLink myweek = new HyperLink();
myweek.Text = "week";
myweek.NavigateUrl = "Summary.aspx";

cell.Controls.Add(myweek);
```

The above `HyperLink` is created dynamically in my control.

When I click on the hyperlink it is opening a pop up window which is expected but the problem is that it is opening with all the information(like addressbar..etc).

What can I change in the above code to display pop up window without toolbar?
Can I do without using Javascript?
Do I need to make any changes to above code to work in FireFox and other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I believe you need Javascript to do this.  You could do something like this:

```
hlWhatever.NavigateUrl = "javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com',null,'resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,status=no,width=125,height=125');"
```

Comment: You may want to set the NavigateUrl to "#" and attach this code to an onclick event, fyi.  I just went back and looked at an old example where I'm doing something similar and that's how I handled it.

Comment: you need to use `htWhatever.Attributes.Add("onclick","<javascript window open code goes here, remember to put return false at the end>"`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
If you prefer to do this in the CS code, then add an onclick attribute and use window.open.
Example:

```
myweek.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com',width='300',height ='300', toolbar='no')";
myweek.NavigateUrl = "#";
```

Comment: as he said , it's opening in a new window . he wants to open a window without addressBar , statusBar and ...

Answer (score 0):

window's appearance properties (having addressBar or ... ) has no relation to HyperLink control so you should not expect it in its properties . 
I'm afraid the only way to do this is through javascript . you can check this [discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1066843.aspx/1).

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned method will work.

```
hyperlink1.Attributes.Add("onclick","javascript:window.open('./ViewItems/product.aspx',null,'resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,status=no,width=350,height=350'); return false");
```